# A way to add up totals in array without double ups

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I am trying to design a program where a user enters in 10 rows of names and money value e.g "Jane 30" 
this is processed into the struct:

```
typedef struct customers {
char names[10][20];
int change[10];} customers;
```

I am trying to figure out the logic to remove any double ups and create a grand total for all users for example, if Jane had been entered more than once, all of her money values would be added up to a total, and so on for any other double ups.

Comment: When you read a new record, check to see if the name matches an earlier record. If it does, add its data to the earlier record and do not add it as a new record. If it does not match an earlier record, add it as a new record.

Comment: What you've got is a **struct of arrays**, which is sometimes useful. But in this case, the more typical approach is an **array of structs**, where each struct has information for one customer. So the member variables are `char name[20];` and `int change;` and the array is `customers users[10];`